# Closing Comments conditionally in comments.php

Tags: php, posts, comments, comments-template

I have a website running shapely as my theme, and I am trying to allow only logged in members to see comments on a post, and restrict anyone but administrators from commenting. I would like comments to appear closed to everyone but administrators while previous comments are still visible to members.

In order to do this I just need to know how to assign a "closed for comments" value to a post, preferably from inside the comments.php file. Basically I would like to change all posts so the function: `comments_open()` returns false, via code.

is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Note that if you just remove the comment form that doesn't mean comments can't be submitted, WP still listens for the comments form submission

Comment: does that still happen if you disable comments from the admin menu?